# Allow user to mark entry as favorite, starred, or saved for later

Tags: entries, users

We're building a site with a recipes catalog and we'd like to allow logged in users to "star" an entry/recipe and then be able to view a list of their "starred" or "favorited" entries. Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Lindsey's recommendation, [Craft Like](https://github.com/dukt/craft-like) by Dukt might also be useful for this. It was updated recently for 2.5 and is open source.

Comment: That looks like it will do exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This definitely sounds like plugin territory. I'd recommend [Curate](https://github.com/lorigoldberg/curate), by Lori Goldberg.

** Disclaimer: I haven't personally tried it.*

Comment: Thanks, Lindsey! I'll have to see if that will work with 2.5.

Comment: It also occurs to me that [Upvote](https://craftpl.us/plugins/upvote) could probably handle this task. I didn't intend to make a shameless plug, and some additional business logic would certainly be required... but it could be definitely be done with Upvote if Curate doesn't work for you.

Comment: Agreed! There are a few around, [Dukt Like](https://dukt.net/craft/like) may also be an option. Good luck!

Comment: I was late to party Matt P. Sorry, you must have posted your comment while I had the answer window open!

Comment: Thanks, guys! Looks like Dukt Like will do exactly what I need.